# Reorganize Language Switcher based on Country/Region

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm working on a site with 34+ languages and will likely be expanding to more. With this many countries, a simple drop-down list can be difficult for usability. I would like to customize the language switcher so that I can categorize a language by region and country. I have seen this before, have created similar on other non-Drupal sites, but haven't seen anything like it for Drupal.

Example:

- Europe

  - Germany

    - DE
  - Switzerland

    - DE
    - FR

etc.

I'm looking for either a module, or a head start on what I might do short of writing some custom PHP for the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a clue from below modules..

- [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) Module ...

> Hierarchical Select module defines the "hierarchical_select" form
>   element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select
>   items in a hierarchy.

[image]

- [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) Module..

> Language Switcher Dropdown is a very simple module that exposes a new
>   block, similar to the default Language Switcher block provided by
>   Locale module. The new block allows site visitors to switch languages
>   using a drop-down select list instead of using hyperlinks.

[image]

- You need to build a custom module which displays region > countries using hierarchical select module
- On Form Submit you need to do below actions which lang drop down does to redirect.

Please find submit handler code below from lang dropdown module..

```
function lang_dropdown_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $language_code = check_plain($form_state['values']['lang_dropdown_select']);
  $type = $form_state['values']['lang_dropdown_type'];
  $tohome = $form_state['values']['lang_dropdown_tohome'];

  $language_codes = locale_language_list('language');
  if (!in_array($language_code, $language_codes)) return;

  $types = language_types_configurable(FALSE);
  if (!in_array($type, $types)) $type = 'language';

  $path = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
  $languages = language_negotiation_get_switch_links($type, $path);

  $language = $languages->links[$language_code];

  $newpath = (isset($language['href']) && $tohome == 0) ? $language['href'] : '<front>';

  if (!isset($language['query'])) {
    $language['query'] = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  }

  $form_state['redirect'] = array($newpath, $language);

}
```